# How to change UIColor in Embeded controller from parent controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uicolor

I am new to Swift and currently stoked with **Delegates**.
I need to change Embedded Controller UIColor from button in a Parent Controller.

Here is what I've tried

1) I created a delegate protocol with func and UIColor as an arumetn
2) Add an instance in Parent VC (ThirdViewController)

Code in a parent VC

```
    import UIKit

protocol TVCDelegate: class {
    func setColor(color: UIColor)
}

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: TVCDelegate?


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? AdditionalThirdViewController {
            vc.setColor(color: UIColor.red) }}

    @IBAction func redButton(_ sender: Any?) {
        I need this button to change color in **Embedded VC** }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() }


    }


}

extension ThirdViewController: TVCDelegate {
    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    } }
```

Code in embedded vc

```
import UIKit

class AdditionalThirdViewController: UIViewController {


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let vc = segue.destination as? ThirdViewController {
            vc.delegate = self } }

    @IBAction func redButton(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
```

Finally I need both controllers to have three buttons and each buttons to change color in other controller.

How can I achieve that?
And also do you have recommendations what to read about delegates for dummies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try and offer a bit more clarification...

The Protocol / Delegate design pattern allows us to "delegate" work to another class / object.

A very commonly used case - where folks don't even realize they're using it - is with table views. The table view itself detects when a user taps a row, and then tells its **delegate** that just happened. At that point, the table view has no idea what action should be taken based on the row selection... it just tells its delegate (the table view controller):

> "Hey! The user selected on of my rows!"

and the controller *conforms* to that protocol by implementing:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // do something because a row was selected
}
```

In this implementation, we know ***who*** is sending that message (`tableView`) and we know which row was selected (`indexPath`). The table view itself doesn't need to know anything about the content of the row or what's supposed to happen next... it ***delegates*** that task to the controller.

In your case, you want to load a view controller into a container view, and have the buttons in that controller tell its delegate (the parent controller) "a button was tapped" and let the parent controller decide what to do -- such as change its background color.

For buttons in the *parent* view controller, you would simply set the `.backgroundColor` property of the container VC's view, or, optionally, call a function in that controller.

I put together a simple, very similar, example of this a couple years ago, and just updated it to better reflect what you are trying to do. You can find it here: https://github.com/DonMag/ContainerDelegate

It looks like this:

[image]

Tapping the Cyan or Orange buttons (in the main controller) will change the background of the VC in the container view.

Tapping the Red or Green buttons in the container view will tell its **delegate**:

> "Hey! A color button was tapped!"

and the delegate function (in the main controller) will change the background color of the big Label.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  I got that :)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you to read this article in detail and understand how delegate works and data around

[https://medium.com/@jamesrochabrun/implementing-delegates-in-swift-step-by-step-d3211cbac3ef](http://How%20to%20implement%20delegate%20step%20by%20step)

In your case you have to call delegate method when button tapped in your ThirdViewController like this.

```
@IBAction func redButton(_ sender: Any?) {
   delegate?.setColor(UIColor.red)
}
```

the above code will invoke delegate method with value red. Now you need to catch this value in EmbededViewController and need to implement TVCDelegate like this

```
extension AdditionalThirdViewController: TVCDelegate {
    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
    //Set Color sent by ThirdViewController
    }
}
```

Again you need to understand delegate basics.

Additionally remove this code you have written in ThirdViewController

```
extension ThirdViewController: TVCDelegate {
    func setColor(color: UIColor) {
        view.backgroundColor = color
    } }
```

Class that declares delegate cannot implement same delegate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the article. I implemented suggested code, but redButton does not change screen color. 

Should I add something to Embedded VC (AdditionalThirdViewController)?

Delegate passes only UIColor value but not Delegates method implementation. 

I added "view.backgroundcolor = color" in extension to Embedded controller, but I think I should call it somehow?

Answer (score -1):

You need to register notification and call it. Let me explain you how can you do that first on button click of first viewcontroller add this code :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "changeColor"), object: nil, userInfo: nil)
```

After added that code go to the third view controller and in viewwillappear add this code :

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YOURVIEWCONTROLLERNAME.changeColor(notification:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "changeColor"), object: nil)
```

after that add this method in thirdviewcontroller

```
 @objc func changeColor(notification: NSNotification)
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
```

You are all set now.